# In what universe do unicorns come from rocks?

Tags: story-identification

In a [recent prank](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454) unicorn coins (*unicoins*) were used to grant powers.  Apparently you could acquire more unicoins by [pounding rocks](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/are-unicoins-aprils-fool-prank/3455#3455). I am not aware of unicorns or unicions hiding in rocks in any universe.  What universe does the concept of unicorns/unicions  from rocks come from?

Comment: I think you may be mistaken. It was unicoins that could be used to gain special powers, not unicorns

Comment: Unicorns found in rocks; http://www.examiner.com/article/unicorn-fossil-origins-china-confirmed

Comment: @Richard edited to correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it was a word-play with the *bitcoin mining*. In the unicoin case the mining was more literal.